# JavaFX binding of a property in another class

Tags: java, javafx

I am pretty new with JavaFX binding and I am trying to understand how to solve the following problem.

I have a Statistic class that contains a String member called "value". The construction of this class doesn't really matter, the only things of importance here is to know that "value" changes overtime (it is event based).

In my JavaFX application, I have a Statistic object, and I would like to bind the value of "value" to a label. To do so, I created a SimpleStringProperty and binded it to "value" like this:

```java
SimpleStringProperty temp = new SimpleStringProperty (s.getStatisticObject().getValue());
```

To listen to the change, to see if it is working or not:

```java
temp.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

But even if the value changes (as in s.getStatisticObject().getValue() will return something different if I invoke it manually every x seconds), the code implemented in the change listener never runs.

To summarize, I have an external class and I would like to bind of if its member to an observable to react when the value changes (in the external class). Hope that makes sense.

I have looked around and tried to find something that would be similar but couldn't (it could be because I am having problems articulating this simple problem).

Comment: OK, so you created a Statistic object and now you want a label which will auto update a value of that objects variable?

Comment: Please read how to post a [mcve] and [edit] the question to include one. Right now, it's quite difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do or how you're trying to do it.

Comment: `new SimpleStringProperty (s.getStatisticObject().getValue())` retrieves the value just before the constructor is invoked. Any changes done to the source later have no effect on the property. *"The construction of this class doesn't really matter"* it DOES matter. You need to react to changes and this requires you to gain knowlege about those changes one way or another. Being able to add an observer one way or another would be a convenient way of doing this. If this is not possible depending on the design of the class this may not be possible at all.